# Why are beavers not considered marine mammals?

Tags: mammals, marine-biology, limnology

They spend a lot of their lives in the water, they have fur, give live birth, have mammary glands etc...but my teacher mentioned that beavers have continually growing teeth (incisors) which supposedly excludes them from being marine mammals. The thing I'm confused about is that we also learned later that manatees & walruses (which are both considered marine mammals DO have continually growing teeth. I don't understand, any help would be appreciated :'(

Comment: It might help you to think carefully about the word "marine"...

Comment: @bob1 It might help you to think carefully about the fact that beavers sometimes brave the sea.

Comment: So do people, are we "marine"? @Araucaria

Comment: @Araucaria true, but does not make them marine any more than whales and dolphins coming into fresh water makes them aquatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Beavers are not Marine Mammals**

According to Wikipedia, [Marine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine) is an adjective meaning of or pertaining to the sea or ocean: as [Beavers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver) can be found in a number of freshwater habitats, such as rivers, streams, lakes and ponds, they are not considered "marine".

**Beavers are semiaquatic Mammals**

Their [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver) page mention that they be [semiaquatic mammals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquatic_mammal) (that dwell partly or entirely in bodies of water), as the [European otter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_otter), the [Baikal seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baikal_seal), the [Capybara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capybara) or the [hippopotamus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopotamus):

> Beavers (genus Castor) are large, semiaquatic rodents
> (...)
> **Other semi-aquatic mammals**, such as water voles, muskrats, minks, and
> otters, will shelter in beaver lodges.

Be nice to your teacher when you correct them about their answer: it's ok to be wrong sometime, even for a teacher! Hope it helps.